# awk returns "The specified path is invalid" error on cmder windows

Tags: regex, windows, awk, cmder

I'm trying this `awk` oneliner from [here](https://github.com/KaTeX/KaTeX/wiki/Examining-TeX) on cmder-Windows10:

```
awk '/> \\box.=/,/^$/{print}'
```

to examine a log file. but I get this error:

> The specified path is invalid.

I know the basics of regular expressions but I can't understand what the above command is supposed to do. I would appreciate if you could help me with:

- elaborate the above command and what it is supposed to return? If I realise that maybe I can replicate it with some native Windows command outside the cmder. probably using `findstr`?
- why am I getting that error? and if/how I can edit the command to resolve the issue?

**P.S.** thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53318583/4999991) I was able to run the command `awk '/box.=/,/^\r\n/' foo` and it works without any error returning what it is expected to return. but I still don't know why the original command returns that error.

Comment: It attempts to match and print lines between 2 patterns. Pattern 1 is `> \box.=` where `.` will match any character. And Pattern 2 is an empty line i.e. `^$`

Comment: I do not understand the parts: `> ` (greater-than space) and `/,/` (slash comma slash). how where is the `" ` (comma space) came from?

Comment: well, the log file I have is too long and it also probably contain some confidential info which I should not share publicly on pastebin or somewhere like that. At this moment I just want to understand what the above command mean. Plus this can actually be replicated in any arbitrary path inside cmder. so it regardless of the log file I have.

Comment: let's break it down. first is the above command a valid `awk` command? if yes why it returns that error? if the pattern does not exists it must return nothing, am I wrong?

Comment: From your link: _You can pipe the result to_ `awk '/> \\box.=/,/^$/{print}'` How do you use that awk? The exact command line, please.

Comment: @JamesBrown I use it exactly as you proposed in your post. `awk ... foo`

Comment: And you get no output, just an error?

Comment: @revo I'm not! why should hide anything from you guys?!!!

Comment: please see my P.S.

Answer (score 1):

Demonstrating what your command does:

```
$ cat foo
nope
> \box.=
this
and this

nope
```

Your script executed:

```
$ awk '/> \\box.=/,/^$/' foo
> \box.=
this
and this
            # this is the empty line
```

If you are running it in Windows `/^$/` might not work since Windows uses `\r\n` newlines. Instead, try:

```
$ awk -v RS="\r\n" '/> \\box.=/,/^$/'` file
```

Comment: thanks. would you please write the complete command with the `\r\n` for windows?

Comment: @Foad, perhaps the line where you're expecting the search to stop is not actually blank. In a unix environment, you could use `od -c` or `cat -t -e` to get a better idea of what's actually in your input file. If you include the output from one of those (or a snippet if the file is large), folks will have a better idea of what you're dealing with.

Comment: @ghoti not sure if I understand your point. but I tested other awk commands on the above proposed foo file and it works. so the file is ok, awk is ok. but there is something in the command which makes it incompatible with cmder environment.

Comment: please see my P.S.